# Disable copy/cut button on Office 2010 ribbon and prevent it from being changed

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ms-office, ribbon

I want to disable copy/cut button on Excel ribbon for a certain workbook, so that when the workbook is shared with others, they cannot use these two buttons.

We can edit CustomUI.xml to disable the buttons, which is easy. However, people who have access to this workbook are also able to edit the xml file to get the buttons enabled. This is unwanted.

I can protect the VB Editor of Excel workbook with password. Therefore, if VB can have control over the ribbon, that would be good. However, I did not find a way to do that.

Is there any way for VB to check whether the buttons are disabled? If users (people who have access to this workbook) enabled the buttons by editing the xml, VB will detect that and hide the sheets, and show a warning message etc.

(I use VB to disable ctrl+c, ctrl+x as well, so that users cannot copy and cut)

Comment: I'm curious as to what the logic behind that would be? It will certainly offer no protection, since as soon as the workbook is opened, if the user disables Macros, your 'copy protection' gets defeated

Comment: There are mechanisms to force macros -- what I did is to hide sheets via vb before closing workbook, and vb will unhide them when the workbook is opened again. If users don't enable macros, they cannot see the sheets.

Comment: But can still unhide them. Security through Obscurity not very robust. If you want to really hide code, write a DLL in C++. If you want to hide data, encrypt it and access it via some nonVBA code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :) I have seen comments on web that Excel is by no means secure (you may not agree I don't know) and the mechanisms I used here and the like are not robust. I talked to my supervisor on this but he insisted that I try to add *some* security, as much as I can. I am curious though, how a user could break the password protection of VB code? What is the way to unhide sheets when macros are disabled, under my mechanism? And for 'encrypt it and access it via some nonVBA code', could you please describe more on feasible approaches?

Comment: Interesting you supervisor has such sensitive data in such insecure state. I have been down that road before. If you could analyse with him/her the degree of security needed on this file then you will know whether its worth keeping it in excel. Just saying.

Comment: I did not talk to that client directly, but I think in our case they just want to make it more difficult to copy the data. I sort of understand that Excel is not secure in the *security* sense, but I think I also need to understand that sometimes *making it difficult to do* is good enough for some people :) Users can even do screenshots and it is fine. However, I would appreciate it if you or anyone can explain to me how VBA Excel protection could be broken to give me a sense how easy it is. If that is too easy, then I didn't even succeed in *making it difficult to do* :)

Comment: But regardless of whether you agree or not, if you know how to use vb to check ribbon, please tell me :) I still want to know whether that is possible.

Comment: There is this series -> Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers with three parts, Part 1, 2 and 3 which you can search for on Google. All details about ribbon manipulation are mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by removing the clipboard group from the Home tab in the Ribbon.

Go to File ==> Option ==> Customize Ribbon

then select `Main Tabs` for the ribbon you wish to customize. Then highlight clipboard from the home group and select remove.

[image]

Comment: But users can add it back right :( Thanks for answering though

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to Ensure the entire worksheet is Locked, then Protect the whole Worksheet with password. This disables cells to be selected and hence copy cannot be achieved.

1. Select the whole worksheet, right click and then **Format Cells** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>)
2. Go to **Protection** tab, tick "Locked" then OK
3. Home ribbon -> Cells group -> Format -> Protect Sheet (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)
4. Put in a strong password and ensure "**Select locked cells**" is not checked
   [image: Protect Sheet]
   (You can even lock down all sheets with different passwords)
5. Click OK and save the workbook (you may want to set another password before it can be opened)

Now people cannot select any cells in the sheet and effectively disabled Select All/Copy. However they can copy the Sheet to a new workbook with same feature (cannot select any cells within).

Note there exists software to break this most kind of protections, but these should do with your bundle of feature lock down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then it will be read-only right? Users should be able to edit, but should not copy/cut. And thank you for reminding me of the possibility of protection broken :) Can see the comments under the question.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a User Form for modifying formulas?